# Is it possible to have make treat a missing dependency as up-to-date?

Tags: makefile

If I have a Makefile as follows

```
server : network.o storage.o logic.o
    ld network.o storage.o logic.o -o server

network.o : network.c netdefs.h
    cc -c -o network.o network.c

storage.o : storage.c defs.h
    cc -c -o storage.o storage.c

logic.o : logic.c defs.h
    cc -c -o logic.o logic.c

.PHONY : promote clean reallyclean

promote : server
    cp server /staging/new_servers

clean : 
    rm -f *.o

reallyclean : clean
    rm -f server
```

And I do the following sequence of commands

```
make server # builds ther server from source
make clean  # tidies up the .o files
make promote # send the built server to the staging area
```

make, not unsurprisingly, re-builds the server from scratch, as the .o files are dependencies of server and are missing.

I do want this to happen if the server file itself is not there (there'd be nothing to promote otherwise) but if there is a server and no .o files then I want make to assume that the server is up-to-date and to promote it.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it!

Use .SECONDARY or .INTERMEDIATE to mark **all** the intermediates that I want to ignore, e.g. add:

```
.SECONDARY : network.o storage.o logic.o
```

(I had tried these but in my real solution I had an ignored intermediate relying on a non-ignored intermediate, so make was still rebuilding the supposedly-ignored intermediate, and hence rebuilding the server.)